# Does "Prima" have a double-meaning (in Mexico)?

Tags: modismos, méxico

I recently saw this billboard in León, Guanajuato, México:

[image: Tecate billboard]

*[Sorry for the awkward placement of the light pole in the photo; I was driving when I snapped it.]*

The sign is an advertisement for Tecate beer, and follows a pattern similar to other Tecate advertisements which also read "Es fácil ser hombre", with some sort of clever or cute photo with a simple caption.  (The one I recall was a wire coat hanger as a TV antenna).

But this one puzzles me.  What does a photo of a woman, and the caption "Prima" mean in this context?

There must be some double-meaning with which I am unfamiliar.

Comment: It can also be used as the words beautiful, lovely and sexy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, "Prima" means the same thing you're most likely thinking (female cousin), the deeper meaning comes from a Mexican (vulgar) saying that goes:

> A la Prima se le arrima

The word `arrima` in this particular case has sexual connotations (kind of bringing your genitals closer to her, so to speak).

Paraphrasing some guy on the [Wordreference forums](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1947320):

Situation: Jorge and Juan are at a coffee shop. Jorge greets a chick that's passing by, and Juan asks: "Quien es ella?"; these are 2 possible scenarios based on that:

1. Jorge states she's his cousin, and says: "Tu prima bien buena, presentame a tu prima, porque a la prima se le arrima, ¿O no?"
2. Jorge states she's Jose's cousin (He's one of their friends), and then says: "Esta buenisima, dile a Jose que me presente a su prima, porque a la prima se le arrima"

So basically as you can see the lady in the advertisement is quite attractive and following the premise that `Es fácil ser hombre` it's easy for a guy to see a beautiful lady and want to do "nasty" things with her or something like that...

Comment: *A la prima se le arrima hasta que gima y si es prima hermana, con más ganas* the complete phrase in Perú.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the word "Prima" also has a specific (and quite boring) meaning in financial /insurance terms, meaning the same as in the english "Primes or Premiums". However, Prima in this instance is referring to the first meaning of this homonym, namely: female cousin.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a lot of female cousins and your wife, girlfriend or date probably won't meet them all. So if you happen to be talking or spending a lot of time with a girl or even seeing someone else and your partner/date questions you about her it's a great excuse to say she is your cousin since she can't get mad that you are spending time with your "family".

> -"Y ¿quién es tu amiguita?","¿De quién es esa foto?", "¿Con quién estabas hablando?", etc.
>
> -"Es mi prima."
>
> -"Ah... ok."

That's why it also says "Es fácil ser hombre"

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you Newbie... although the other answers I have seen so far are OK as well. Nevertheless, I would say that your interpretation of the advertisement is much closer to what the Tecate marketing people were trying to convey.

Answer (score 2):

@darkajax answer gives probably the most accurate connotation, but I'd say that it's not the only one. `A la prima se le arrima` is unarguably the topic they evoke with the word `prima` in there, but `arrimar` is not *always* an euphemism for "bringing your genitals closer to her". It also means just

> *"introduce me to your cousin, that's what you are expected to do with a cousin!"*.

Therefore, I don't consider it always as an offense. Of course in the Tecate poster, it's the vulgar connotation they refer to, but I complement darkajax's answer just to let people know that the phrase it's not always that vulgar.

Comment: Good point! Its one of the most prevalent "Rhyme sayings". In mexico we're particularly fond of those

Answer (score 1):

Prima in proper spanish is a cousin. However, in colloquial terms or slang, prima can be a good friend one socializes with often. Like homegirl in english.